# Links in Safari and ul

Tags: css, html-lists

I have a general css rule for a link that works fine till I put an exception. In this specific case simplified, the general links should be black and the exception should be red. But when I add the ".menu a:link" everything goes red.

The problem is only in Safari, not other browsers. In places like FsFiddle or JsBin everything is ok.

Am I doing anything wrong?

HTML:

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#">should be red</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">should be red</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">should be red</a></li>
</ul>

<a href="aligues.html"> should be black </a> <br>
```

CSS:

```
a { outline:0; text-decoration: none ; }
a:link, a:visited { color: black; }
a:hover { color: black;text-decoration: none; }  

.menu a:link, a:visited { color: red; }
.menu a:hover { color: red;text-decoration: none; }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note that you haven't prepended your `a:visited` selector with `.menu`.

I am going to guess that specific line should look like this:

```
.menu a:link, 
.menu a:visited { color: red; }
```

The reason it is only red in safari is because that's the only browser that visited `aligues.html`.

Comment: That's it! I have been hours with this silly mistake and you solved in minutes. Thank you so much!

Comment: Both answers are perfect and at the same time. The system do not let me choose both

Comment: As a tip; put a newline after each comma in css. even when you oneline the properties, it will make mistakes such as this immediately obvious. Or use a CSS pre-processor like LESS/SCSS.

Comment: The counter seem to indicate that this came 1 minute before

Comment: I was about 40 seconds earlier :p

Answer (score 3):

It looks as though there's a rule you may have not realised is taking affect.

```
.menu a:link, a:visited { color: red; }
```

This rule actually specifies that all links inside the menu are red as well as ALL links that have been visited. So it seems that you may have visited the other links around the page and safari is just marking them as read?

I created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cchana/DmfVr/) that shows the link outside of the `ul` with a URL you are likely to have visited, it should show red. The fix is to make the selector less generic. For example:

```
.menu a:link, .menu a:visited { color: red; }
```

Comment: That's it! I have been hours with this silly mistake and you solved in minutes. Thank you so much!

Comment: Both answers are perfect and at the same time. The system do not let me choose both

Comment: @Nrc not a problem, glad you got your answer!